# Swift 3 - How to append NSMutableArray objects to another NSMutableArray

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, swift3

I wan to append objects from a `NSMutablArray` to another `NSMutableArray` on Swift 3 but I can't achieve that.

This is what I tried to do first:

```
mutableArray.addObjects(from: anotherMutableArray)
```

And I got this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray?' to expected argument type '[Any]'

Then I tried this:

```
mutableArray.addObjects(from: anotherMutableArray as [Any])
```

And I got this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray?' to type '[Any]' in coercion

How can I append objects from a `NSMutableArray` to another `NSMutableArray` on Swift 3?

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast the `NSMutableArray` to a Swift array of `AnyObject`, not `Any`.

```
mutableArray.addObjects(from: anotherMutableArray as [AnyObject])
```

Comment: Now I get the error: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray?' to type '[AnyObject]' in coercion`

Comment: Is your `anotherMutableArray` optional? Is so, you need to deal with it properly just like any optional.